# Why isn't cin >> string working with Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, string, cin

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

This isn't working. Why?

Comment: The next time you ask questions, you should try to be a bit more concrete, i.e. compiler errors etc.

Comment: "This isn't working" provides almost no information. Compiler error? Run-time crash? No output? We have no idea. Whenever you are tempted to say "This isn't working", instead please post the thing that happens instead of what you expect.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Because you forgot to `#include <string>`

Comment: That was it. It worked with Dev-C++ though.

Comment: Probably because its <iostream> includes <string> already.

Comment: Dev-C++ probably automatically did an `#include <string>` (or an implicit one) for you.

Comment: The format of the question (and answer) made me think it was one of those "normal people" jokes. ;)

Answer (score 9):

You should `#include <string>`