# Works with g++ but not MSVC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t cin >> string working with Visual C++ 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343035/why-isnt-cin-string-working-with-visual-c-2010)

The first program I wrote [refuses to compile](http://pastebin.com/6jpf6WF8) in Visual C++, and it looks like it's complaining that the '>>' operator isn't defined for istream.

After looking it over carefully, it seemed to be correct, so I checked with g++ and it compiles fine (and has no warnings with -Wall).

So why does it work with g++ but not Visual C++?

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<std::string> list;
    std::string str = "";
    std::cin >> str;
    while (str.compare("q") != 0) {
        list.push_back(str);
        std::cin >> str;
    }

    std::cout << "You entered: \n";

    for (std::list<std::string>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I had thought C++ code written for Visual C++ and C++ code written for g++ would be nearly identical in most circumstances.

How different are they, how often would you say these kinds of issues come up, and do you know of anywhere I can find some of these differences/gotchas?

Comment: Not only that, but the duplicate has a much better title.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Unfortunately, the duplicate has 500% worse content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different compilers have different headers that internally include other headers. gcc is probably including `<string>` inside of `<iostream>`, while Visual Studio's `<iostream>` doesn't include `<string>`. Try putting:

```
#include <string>
```

At the top with your other includes. `<string>` is the header file that defines `operator>>(std::istream, std::string)` (in other words, `<string>` is the header that "officially" provides the function you need to do `std::cin >> str;`).

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-6-an-inclusion-pitfall/